# Python parallel programming “No traceback available"

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, ipython-parallel

I am trying to run parallel code in python utilizing [`ipyparallel`](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
# create client & view
rc = ipp.Client()
dv = rc[:]
v = rc.load_balanced_view()

def my(i):    
     import numpy as np
     aa[:,:,i]=np.dot(uanom_L[:,:,i-I_a:i+I_a+1],lcoz_a)
     bb[:,:,i]=np.dot(uanom_L[:,:,i-I_b:i+I_b+1],lcoz_b) 
     print(i)
     return aa,bb       

aaa=v.map(my,np.arange(I_a,c-I_a))
aaa.get()
```

Yet, I got the following error,

```
[3:apply]: No traceback available
[2:apply]: No traceback available
[1:apply]: No traceback available
[0:apply]: No traceback available
```

8773 more exceptions ...

Any ideas 
Thanks

Comment: You might check the logs in the controller to see if there was something about failing to produce the traceback. What are the versions of: ipython, ipykernel, ipyparallel. Also, the following information is missing from the example: I_a, c, I_b, lcoz_a, lcoz_b, uanom_L

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am wondering how can I check from the controller?. Here is the version: ipykernel-4.3.1-py27_0, ipyparallel-5.2.0-py27_0, ipython-4.1.2-py27_1. Regarding to the missing information--I_a, c, I_b, Icoz_a, Icoz_b, uanom_L--- I can send you npz file containing all those variables.  Thanks